# How can i connect to Azure Data Lake Analysis with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Hi i analyze system log using Azure Data Lake Analysis.

And, i meet a problem that connect Blob Storage from Data Lake Analysis(U-SQL)

This U-SQL shows that read file from blob storage

Before launching this U-SQL, I create test2 blob storage and testcon container

(and set access policy)

```
@searchlog = 
EXTRACT UserId          int, 
        Start           DateTime, 
        Region          string, 
        Query           string, 
        Duration        int, 
        Urls            string, 
        ClickedUrls     string
FROM @"wasb://testcon@test2/SearchLog.tsv"
USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

But i meet a exception.

```
Error
E_STORE_USER_FAILURE

Message
Secret not found for the specified user account Cosmos Path: wasb://testcon@test2/SearchLog.tsv
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: "test2" is your actual Windows Azure Blob Storage account? See [About Azure storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account)

Comment: "test2" is not real account.( just example ). But my real account is not incorrect. I also try "test2.blob.core.windows.net" and result is same.

Comment: Is your Windows Azure Blob Storage account registered with your Azure Data Lake Analytics Account? From the Azure Portal go to your Azure Data Lake Analytics Account. Then click Data Sources. Do you see your storage account listed?  If no, click Add Data Source and then add your Windows Azure Blob Storage account.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solve the problem by your comment.

Comment: Happy to hear.  I have added [Registering Your Windows Azure Blob Storage account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771650.aspx#registerWABS) to U-SQL Language Reference. Will post info as Answer rather than a Comment.

Comment: I have added the storage acount as a connected data source but still having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your Windows Azure Blob Storage account is registered with your Azure Data Lake Analytics account.  I have copied the steps below from [Registering Your Windows Azure Blob Storage account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771650.aspx#registerWABS).

1. Navigate to the Azure Portal and log in.
2. Navigate to your Azure Data Lake Analytics Account.
3. Select Data Sources under Settings.
4. Verify whether your WABS account is listed. If yes, stop here. If no, continue to next step.
5. Click Add Data Source.
6. Select Azure Storage from the Storage Type drop-down list.
7. Select Select Account from the Selection Method drop-down list.
8. Select your WABS account from the Azure Storage drop-down list.
9. Click Add.